# Many entries with OnItemsChanged(), how to delete old entries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to xaml. Entries are added into scrolling view and with the event change. There are many entries being logged causing memory consumption. How to delete entries that are entered earlier. And those entries on deletion should not appear in scroll view too. Thanks in advance.

Here is xaml

```
<local:ScrollingLV x:Name="LogView" Width="300" Height="100"   Margin="10,0,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding LogMsg}">
```

Here is the code that adds to the scroll view

```
public partial class ScrollingLV : ListView
{
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            int iCount = e.NewItems.Count;
            if (iCount > 0)
            {
                this.ScrollIntoView(e.NewItems[iCount - 1]);
            }
        }

       base.OnItemsChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to delete the entries in ListView. I have used this code to delete and it did not work. with NotifyCollectionsChangedEventArgs. e.OldItems.Clear()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ObservableCollection, it is as simple as removing an item from that listview

for example you can refer to this msdn entry https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365(v=vs.110).aspx